# MYSQL - Total count with group by and limit

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have this query and I want to get the count too in it, limit by is important. Previously I used a left join - selecting count of the same query I used in select, but it took a lot of time (I have pasted the simplified version, there are many inner joins too). Is there a way that I can get the count while using the limit??

```
SELECT t1.*  FROM 
(SELECT b.book_id FROM books b 
WHERE b.book_id NOT IN (68, 1019) group by b.book_id limit 0,30) t1
```

The previous version was something like this (not exact):

```
SELECT t1.*  FROM 
    (SELECT b.book_id,t2.books_count FROM books b 
    left join (SELECT book_id,count(book_id) as books_count  from books) t2 on b.book_id = t2.book_id
    WHERE b.book_id NOT IN (68, 1019) group by b.book_id limit 0,30) t1
```

Comment: Slow queries are almost always because there are no indexes or inappropriate indexes. You should publish your actual query, table definitions sample data, expected outcome and an explain plan.

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY? this is a lottery and makes no sense.